# Static variable not incrementing and the screen is not being drawn

Tags: java

The program is supposed to print dots out in a rectangle that represent the screen resolution. The dots are not printing out after you enter the screen resolution, and the static variable screenCount is not keeping track of how many screens were made. It just stays at 1.

```
public class Screen
{
   private static int screenCount;
   private int height;
   private int width;

   public Screen()
   {
      screenCount = 0;
      height = 0;
      width = 0;
   }
   public Screen(int newHeight, int newWidth)
   {
      height = newHeight;
      width = newWidth;

   }   
   public int getHeight()
   {
      return height;
   }    
   public int getWidth()
   {
      return width;
   }   
   public boolean setHeight(int newHeight)
   {
      if (newHeight <= 1080 && newHeight >= 720)
      {
         height = newHeight;
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("ERROR height");
         return false;
      }      
   }   
   public boolean setWidth(int newWidth)
   {
      if (newWidth <= 1920 && newWidth <= 1280)
      {        
         width = newWidth;
         return true;
      }
      else
      {
         System.out.println("ERROR width");
         return false;
      }

   }   
   public void draw()
   {
      screenCount++;
      for(int i = 0; i < height; i++)
      {
         for(int j = 1; j <= width; j++)
          {

            System.out.print(".");

         }
         System.out.println();
      }               
   }

   public static int getScreenCount()
   {
      return screenCount;
   }   
}




// Tester
import java.util.Scanner;
public class ScreenBuilder
{


   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      String again = "";
      do
      {

         Screen myScreen = new Screen();
         int myScreenHeight = 0;
         int myScreenWidth = 0;
         Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
         do
         {
            System.out.println("Enter desired height of screen (720 - 1080)");
            myScreenHeight = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
         }
         while(!(myScreen.setHeight(myScreenHeight)));

         System.out.println();

         do
         {
            System.out.println("Enter desired width of screen (1280 - 1920)");
            myScreenHeight = kb.nextInt();
            System.out.println();
         }
         while(!(myScreen.setWidth(myScreenWidth)));


         myScreen.draw();

         System.out.println("There were " + Screen.getScreenCount() + " Screens Printed");


         Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Would you like to build another screen (Y/N)?");
         again = answer.nextLine();
      }  
      while ("y".equalsIgnoreCase(again));

 }

}
```

Comment: What's your input and output?

Comment: For a start, you ought to fix up `newWidth <= 1920 && newWidth <= 1280`. It should probably be `newWidth <= 1920 && newWidth >= 1280`.

Comment: I fixed it to     (newWidth <= 1920 && newWidth >= 1280) , and now it won't let me enter a value for width. It prints the ERROR width message and asks for another width value.

Comment: Remember to `kb.nextLine()` after entering height. `kb.nextInt()` does not count newline character.
And you are putting `width` to `myScreenHeight` while checking `width` with `myScreenWidth`.

Comment: Ah, thank you. I fixed that.Now, the dots are printing like they are supposed to in a rectangle, but printing Screen.getScreenCount() just gives me 1 everytime.

Comment: You reset the value of `screenCount` in the constructor of `Screen`. And you do it every single loop.

Comment: I took the static variable out of the constructor and initialized it to 0 at the top,and that fixed it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Private static variable is accessible only within that class try with public static int Screencount it might help.